# In arm assembly, how can I create an array then increment each element by 10, for example?

Tags: arrays, linux, assembly, gcc, arm

I would like to modify and complete an example found in my textbook (Harris-Harris). How can I make a program that declares an array of 5 elements for example and then increments each element by 10? This program must also print the elements of the array.

[image]

I've searched some resources and figured out that there are various ways to create an array in Assembly ARM. In these examples that I found, however, there are directives that I don't understand (for example .word or .skip) that are not explained in my textbook.

Comment: What toolchain are you programming for?  `.word` and `.skip` are directives for the GNU assembler.  You might be using a different one.

Comment: Also, what storage class do you want your array to be in?  Shall it be on the stack or just in the data segment?

Comment: I use QEMU with Raspberry PI (Raspbian). I think that it uses GNU assembler (in fact I compile the programs with gcc or with `make` command). As for the second question, I honestly have no idea. I'd just like to complete the example (I think it's okay for the array to be in the data segment). I just push/pop `ip` and `lr` and use registers `r0` through `r3`, just like in the example.

Comment: In my textbook it doesn't mention "data segment", do you mean `.data` ? I'm not sure what it is, I've only seen a few resources

Comment: Then it seems that you are using the GNU assembler.  Read the GNU assembler manual for how directives like `.word` and `.skip` work.  They are indeed correct for setting up arrays in the data segment (which is what the `.data` directive switches to).

Answer (score 1):

Hope this helps. This example uses the stack to allocate the array.

See [assembly memory allocation directives](https://bob.cs.sonoma.edu/IntroCompOrg-RPi/sec-reg-use.html#p-1661) for more help on allocating global variables. Moving the variable `scores` into global scope of the file `test.c` below can reveal the assembly code for that sort of solution.

What is below comes from a quick walk thru of [Hello world for bare metal ARM using QEMU](https://balau82.wordpress.com/2010/02/28/hello-world-for-bare-metal-arm-using-qemu/)

Output of these steps will add 10 to 5 array integers and print their values. The code is in `c` but instructions are provided on how to display the code as assembly so you can study the array allocation and utilization.

Here is the expected output:

```
SCORE  10
SCORE  10
SCORE  10
SCORE  10
SCORE  10
ctrl-a x
QEMU: Terminated
```

These are the commands, notice `startup.s` is assembly code, `test.c` is c code like left side of your post, and `test.ld` is a linker script file to create the image QEMU needs `test.bin` to execute. Also, notice `test.elf` is available with debug symbols for use in `gdb`.

```
arm-none-eabi-as -mcpu=arm926ej-s -g startup.s -o startup.o
arm-none-eabi-gcc -c -mcpu=arm926ej-s -g test.c -o test.o
arm-none-eabi-ld -T test.ld test.o startup.o -o test.elf
arm-none-eabi-objcopy -O binary test.elf test.bin

qemu-system-arm -M versatilepb -m 128M -nographic -kernel test.bin
```

To examine assembly code in gdb see commands below.

Notice the array `scores` in this code is on the stack, [read about local stack variables for ARM assembly here](https://bob.cs.sonoma.edu/IntroCompOrg-RPi/sec-varstack.html) and examine the assembly instructions below at `0x10888` where `sp` is incremented by 24 (20 for `scores` and 4 for `i`).

```
qemu-system-arm -M versatilepb -m 128M -nographic -kernel test.bin -s -S

arm-none-eabi-gdb test.elf -ex "target remote:1234"
(gdb) b c_entry
(gdb) cont
(gdb) x/20i c_entry
   0x10180 <c_entry>:   push    {r11, lr}
   0x10184 <c_entry+4>: add r11, sp, #4
   0x10188 <c_entry+8>: sub sp, sp, #24
```

I use a macbook and install tools like this, they end up in `/usr/local/bin`:

```
brew install --cask gcc-arm-embedded
brew install qemu
```

The c code used is similar to what you posted and combines the article snip w/ a function to print an integer. References are inline of the code.

```c
// test.c
// https://balau82.wordpress.com/2010/02/28/hello-world-for-bare-metal-arm-using-qemu/
volatile unsigned int *const UART0DR = (unsigned int *)0x101f1000;

void print_uart0(const char *s) {
  while (*s != '\0') {             /* Loop until end of string */
    *UART0DR = (unsigned int)(*s); /* Transmit char */
    s++;                           /* Next char */
  }
}

// https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/c-program-to-print-all-digits-of-a-given-number/
void print_int(int N) {
  #define MAX 10
  char arr[MAX]; // To store the digit of the number N
  int i = MAX - 1;
  int minus = ( N < 0 );
  int r;

  arr[i--] = 0;
  while (N != 0) { // Till N becomes 0
    r = N % 10;    // Extract the last digit of N
    arr[i--] = r + '0';  // Put the digit in arr[]
    N = N / 10;    // Update N to N/10 to extract next last digit
  }
  arr[i] = ( minus ) ? '-' : ' ';
  print_uart0(arr + i );
}

void c_entry() {
  int i;
  int scores[5] = {0, 0, 0, 0, 0};
  for (i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    scores[i] += 10;
    print_uart0("SCORE ");
    print_int( scores[i] );
    print_uart0("\n");
  }
}
```

Using the same `startup.s` assembly from article:

```
.global _Reset
_Reset:
 LDR sp, =stack_top
 BL c_entry
 B .
```

Using the same linker script from article:

```
ENTRY(_Reset)
SECTIONS
{
 . = 0x10000;
 .startup . : { startup.o(.text) }
 .text : { *(.text) }
 .data : { *(.data) }
 .bss : { *(.bss COMMON) }
 . = ALIGN(8);
 . = . + 0x1000; /* 4kB of stack memory */
 stack_top = .;
}
```